# Java Enterprise Architecture Reference

Tags: java, jakarta-ee

I'm looking for a good reference about Java Enterprise Architecture design and principles.

I searched a little bit but what I found was just old books which does offer old technologies.

> > Is there any reliable reference around which is new and comprehensive ? how about video training ?

Thanks a lot in advance

Comment: ftp://mirror01.transact.net.au/sourceforge/f/project/fi/fileuploads/scea/sun-certified-enterprise-architect.pdf

Comment: The official JavaEE tutorial maybe? http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/tutorial/doc/docinfo.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you may start with some training lab

**[Certification Training Lab](http://www.epractizelabs.com/certification/sun/scea-5-part1-exam.html)**

**[Certification Training Lab](http://www.epractizelabs.com/certification/sun/scea-5-part23-exam.html)**

**[Java Solution](http://www.e-zest.net/technologies/j2ee-competency/java-solution-consulting/)**

**[Java Enterprise tutorial](http://www.vtc.com/products/J2EE-Java-2-Enterprise-Edition-tutorials.htm)**

but i found this material will be good.

**[Lynda java enterprise taining](http://www.lynda.com/Java-training-tutorials/1077-0.html)**

**[oracle university training](http://education.oracle.com/pls/web_prod-plq-dad/db_pages.getpage?page_id=609&p_org_id=1080544&lang=US&get_params=dc%3aD70926GC10,p_preview%3aN)**

and one book **[Pro Java EE Spring Patterns
Best Practices and Design Strategies Implementing Java EE Patterns with the Spring Framework](http://www.apress.com/9781430210092/)** might help you.

Answer (score 0):

This may help you. There are list of books in [this](http://avik-ganguly.blogspot.com/2012/09/oracle-certified-master-enterprise.html) page. [Oracle Certified Master Java Enterprise Architect Java EE 7 
Certification Guide](http://www.apress.com/9781430250012) also good reference but i am not sure is there any pdf version of this.

Answer (score 0):

http://javabrains.koushik.org/p/java-ee.html visit this website to see the videos about java

Answer (score 0):

Best book about Java EE design i ever read is Real World Java EE Patterns Rethinking Best Practices by Adam Bien http://realworldpatterns.com/